# replacing a row in sqlite if it exists

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, cordova

How can I make a **javascript** call too **sqlite** to **update a row** in a table if it exists, and create that row if it does not exist **in phonegap**.

currently, a line like the following will successfully **create** a row in google chrome

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO "+tablename
                    +" (fieldName,fieldValue,fieldComment) VALUES 
                    ('"+name+"', '"+value+"', '"+comment+"');",[], 
                    this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
```

however, when i try the following (as I supposed it should be done from here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html), nothing happens:

```
transaction.executeSql("REPLACE "+tablename+" (fieldName,fieldValue,fieldComment) 
                       VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+value+"', '"+comment+"');",[],
                        this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
```

(this is after calling `"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueName ON "+tablename+" ("+name+")";`)

the same happens with

```
 transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO OR REPLACE "+tablename+" (fieldName,fieldValue,fieldComment) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+value+"', '"+comment+"');",[], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
```

(also is after calling "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueName ON "+tablename+" ("+name+")";)

and with

```
 transaction.executeSql("DELETE FROM "+tablename+" where \"fieldName\" EQUALS "+name+";",[], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
 transaction.executeSql("INSERT "+tablename+" (fieldName,fieldValue,fieldComment) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+value+"', '"+comment+"');",[], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
```

I have the calls surrounded by a try statement, hoping that a problematic call would throw an exception, but nothing has happened.

I cannot believe I am asking this question, but after several weeks of nothing, I figured it was time to ask.  If anyone knows of a way to debug sqlite in javascript, please let me know.  I am testing the databases in google chrome (ctrl+shift+i->resources->databases), on a windows 7 dell inspiron.)